# tinymce 4 editor is not inserting HTML tags while inserting data

Tags: jquery, tinymce, tinymce-4

I am using [jQuery Form Plug-in](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/), while I am inserting data into the DB. When I tried to insert HTML content into the MySQL that formed in TinyMCE, HTML content did not inserted, only plaintext inserted. But when I edited the content with TinyMCE, HTML content that formed in TinyMCE was updated without any problem. I am using codes like this:

```
setup: function(editor) {
    editor.on('init', function(){ tinymce.triggerSave(); });
    editor.on('change', function () { tinymce.triggerSave(); });
},
```

And I'm using this code in the ajaxForm().

```
$("#form_id").bind("form-pre-serialize",function(){
    tinymce.triggerSave()
});
```

Is there any bug?

Comment: I believe you need to update the content of the text area to have html codes before sending via AJAX

Comment: Sounds like your HTML may be getting escaped. Are you calling `strip_tags()` or another escaping function before inserting the data?

Comment: No I dont use an function about cleaning.

Comment: show us your code that you call `formSubmit` or related methods?